# Issue Changing Chrome Language Settings in AWS Lambda with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, aws-lambda

I have developed a web automation that works flawlessly on my local system using Python and Selenium. This automation uses headless Chrome to open a specific web page and fetch its content. On my local system, I can easily set the browser's language settings to English. However, when I transfer the same code to AWS Lambda, I'm unable to change the browser's language settings, and the page content always returns in German.
I'm running it as a function in the eu-central-1 region on AWS Lambda and using AWS Elastic Container Registry (ECR) for Chrome and ChromeDriver. I upload my code to Lambda using AWS CLI.
My Code:
In browserSettings.py, I have defined a BrowserAutomation class:
Hello,

I have developed a web automation that works flawlessly on my local system using Python and Selenium. This automation uses headless Chrome to open a specific web page and fetch its content. On my local system, I can easily set the browser's language settings to English. However, when I transfer the same code to AWS Lambda, I'm unable to change the browser's language settings, and the page content always returns in German.

I'm running it as a function in the eu-central-1 region on AWS Lambda and using AWS Elastic Container Registry (ECR) for Chrome and ChromeDriver. I upload my code to Lambda using AWS CLI.

My Code:

In browserSettings.py, I have defined a BrowserAutomation class:Hello,

I have developed a web automation that works flawlessly on my local system using Python and Selenium. This automation uses headless Chrome to open a specific web page and fetch its content. On my local system, I can easily set the browser's language settings to English. However, when I transfer the same code to AWS Lambda, I'm unable to change the browser's language settings, and the page content always returns in German.

I'm running it as a function in the eu-central-1 region on AWS Lambda and using AWS Elastic Container Registry (ECR) for Chrome and ChromeDriver. I upload my code to Lambda using AWS CLI.
My Code:
In browserSettings.py, I have defined a BrowserAutomation class:

```
from tempfile import mkdtemp
import glob
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
class BrowserAutomation:
    def __init__(self, link):
        self.link = link
        self.driver = self.create_driver_instance()

    @staticmethod
    def set_chrome_options():
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
        chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
        chrome_options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={mkdtemp()}")
        chrome_options.add_argument(f"--data-path={mkdtemp()}")
        chrome_options.add_argument(f"--disk-cache-dir={mkdtemp()}")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")*
        chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
        chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-tools')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--no-zygote')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--hide-scrollbars')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--enable-logging')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--log-level=0')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--v=99')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--single-process')
        chrome_options.add_argument("--lang=en-US")
        prefs = {
            # "profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2,
            "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2,
            "profile.default_content_setting_values.cookies": 2,
            "intl.accept_languages": "en-US",
            "geo.enabled": True,
            "geo.provider.use_corelocation": True,
            "geo.prompt.testing": True,
            "geo.prompt.testing.allow": True,
        }

        chrome_options.binary_location = glob.glob("/var/task/chrome/linux64/*/chrome")[0]
        service = ChromeService(glob.glob("/var/task/chromedriver/linux64/*/chromedriver")[0])
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
        return service, chrome_options

    @staticmethod
    def create_driver_instance():
        service, chrome_options = BrowserAutomation.set_chrome_options()
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
        return driver
```

And I call this class from another script like this:

```
from browserSettings import BrowserAutomation
url = "https://www.google.com/maps"
browser = BrowserAutomation(url)
browser.driver.get(browser.link)
```

How can I successfully change the language settings of Chrome when running on AWS Lambda with Selenium and Python? Do you have any configuration suggestions or alternative solutions to solve this issue?